# Constraints in iOS development

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout

Is it a right choice to start developing with Xcode without add any constraints and just developing with a unique device (for example iPhone 7) running its own simulator; and when the application is finished adding all the constraints for the other devices?

Comment: Personally I don't like the approach to have all done to set constraints. While adding constraints you can figure some *constraints* that will lead to change some layout aspects. Doing all the design and applying constraints later you can face some big changes. Mainly when you go from iPhone to iPad or iPhone early versions

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do:

1. It is right choice when you want to quickly test some idea or test network layer of the app and you don't care about UI.
2. It is bad choice if you are writing production code that will be delivered on Appstore and you plan to fix it later. That "fix it later" might be really annoying task to do and you certainly don't want to create more annoying work for yourself.